# NSURLSession has been renamed to URLSession

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to parse JSON data in Swift 3. When I try to print the whole have problem.

This is the console output of my JSON file:

```
{
  "nameJt1": "01/07/1985",
  "codeVideo1": "_NfijT6mt6A",

  "nameJt2": "02/07/1985",
  "codeVideo1": "XCabcwrxbNc",

  "nameJt3": "03/07/1985",
  "codeVideo3": "XCabcwrxbNc"
}
```

This is my code to parse the file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Jt1Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Jt2Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Jt3Label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //1
        let urlAsString = "http://tvlaayoune.ma/youtubeJT"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
        let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        //2
        let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            var err: NSError?

            // 3
            var jsonJt = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as! NSDictionary
            if (err != nil) {
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }

            // 4
            let nameJt1: String! = jsonJt["nameJt1"] as! String
            let nameJt2: String! = jsonJt["nameJt2"] as! String
            let nameJt3: String! = jsonJt["nameJt3"] as! String

            let codeVideo: String! = jsonJt["codeVideo"] as! String

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                Jt1Label.text = nameJt1
                Jt1Labe2.text = nameJt2
                Jt1Labe3.text = nameJt3

            })
        })
        // 5
        jsonQuery.resume()
    }
}
```

I can't understand what the problem is. Can anyone give me a hand? Thank you in advance.

This is a screenshot showing the code:

[image]

Comment: What is the question? How to parse your JSON? It would help if you told us what you expected. What the error message means?, It's right there in the description. From the //1, //2, //3 littered throughout your code I suspect that you've pasted in some code you found in a tutorial and tried to adapt it, but you still haven't clearly stated a question.

Comment: Just click the red icon Xcode will suggest a fix. And yes the 'NS' prefix is removed and now it is just URLSession

Answer (score 1):

The error is not related to your JSON data structure.

If you click the red circle in the code column, then the suggested fix will replace NSURLSession with URLSession. You can also do this manually.

There are a lot of resources out there that can help you with Swift and JSON, but have a look at this post - it covers both topics, and includes some content on the change from NSURLSession... to URLSession.

https://grokswift.com/updating-nsurlsession-to-swift-3-0/

Comment: Yup. (Voted.) Xcode will likely even offer to make the change for you. To the OP, note that you should be using Swift native types rather than Objective-C versions, so should replace `NSDictionary` with `Dictionary`. You may even want to use `[String:Any]` so that you can fetch key/value pairs without having to cast the key to a `String`.